# Why to pass values to the super class? subclass to super

Tags: oop, flutter, dart, object-oriented-analysis

I was checking [Equatable package](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) "how to use" examples and they pass values to the **super** class, and this subject like a blind spot for me, and I see it everywhere:

```dart
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Person extends Equatable {
  final String name;

  // why? what's happening behind the scene here?
  Person(this.name) : super([name]);
}
```

another example

```dart
@immutable
abstract class MyEvent extends Equatable {
  MyEvent([List configs = const []]) : super(configs);
}
```

1- why we do that? why to pass values for abstract thing? for a blueprint? what's the use of this?

2- why sometimes developers pass values for abstract class like this?

3- what's happening behind the scene here?

4- what is the use cases for such a code?

thanks a lot.

Comment: @Nexevis Hi, in fact I know this, my question is why to pass values for abstract thing? for a blueprint? what's the use of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class being abstract doesn't exclude that it has some concrete members in Dart.

Take the following class as an example:

```dart
abstract class Foo {
  Foo(this.value);

  final int value;

  @override
  String toString() => value.toString();
}
```

While it is abstract, it has a concrete implementation of the property `value`, that is initialized via a custom constructor.

And since the parameter is required, the subclass **must** call the super constructor like so:

```dart
class Subclass extends Foo {
  Subclass(): super(42); 
}
```

Comment: I see. "since the parameter is required" was the key. so it's the only way to mark an ```attribute``` as required by allow only parameterized constructors, so ```The superclass 'Foo' doesn't have a zero argument constructor.``` will be the result. thanks I lot.

Comment: Constructors parameters aren't necessarily required though.